# Is it possible to start counting from a specific div in Python using XPATH and Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have 80 divs, each div (in our case, class 24, 27, 30) contains 2 children.

Is it possible to start counting from let's say, the 24rd row (EXCLUDING CHILDREN), then keep counting the rows under it? (using XPATH only, not CSS selectors ;) )

```
<div class="container">
    ... # dots signify the divs before it
    <div class="24">
        <div class="25"></div>
        <div class="26"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="27">
        <div class="28"></div>
        <div class="29"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="30">
        <div class="31"></div>
        <div class="32"></div>
    </div>
    ... # divs after it
</div>
```

Is there something like:

Let's say:

```py
x = 0
all_the_divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div/*")
while x < len(all_the_divs):
    # do something
    pass
    if x == 24:
        # catch all the divs under 24 (excluding 24)
        # something like:
        divs_under_x = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div/div[" + str(x) + "]::"))
       # or
       divs_under_x = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div/following-sibling::div[" + str(x) + "]*"))
        break
    x += 1
```

OUTPUT: The length should be 2 (class 27 and 30 without their children)
Many thanks.

Comment: there are no any "children" in your code so I would say it is not possible or possible with a regular expression which will consider indent

Comment: Two things: First, to add to what @DmitriT said, you don't have 40 rows X 2; but simply 80 rows, indented differently. Second, in your code you say (in the comment) you want to exclude 24, but your desired output includes 24.

Comment: @DmitriT Thank you for pointing that out, I have fixed the errors in my code.

Comment: @JackFleeting, correct! I have fixed it. Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: It's possible to to do that, though I personally can do it only using lxml, not selenium. Let me know if you're interested and I'll post it.

Comment: @JackFleeting, I'm very interested. I think I might be able to pull it off together with selenium. Many thanks, Jack!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you need to be in the node you want to have the sibling of (if you want to have the siblings of `class="24"`, you need to be ***inside*** the node of `class="24"`.

***i.e.***

```py
x = 0
all_the_divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div/*")
while x < len(all_the_divs):
    # do something
    pass
    if x == 24:
        # catch all the divs under 24 (excluding 24)
        divs_under_x = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div/div[" + str(x) + "]/following-sibling::*"))
        print(len(divs_under_x))
        break
    x += 1
```

This will print out how many divs are under `class="24"` except its children.

Answer (score 1):

Here goes:

```
from lxml import etree

data = [your data above]


tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(data, parser=lxml.etree.HTMLParser())
targets = tree.xpath("*//div[(position()=2 or position()=3) and descendant::div]")
for i in targets:
    for child in i.getchildren():
        child.getparent().remove(child)
    print(etree.tostring(i).decode().replace('\n','').strip())
```

Output:

```
<div class="27">        </div>
<div class="30">         </div>
```

Hopefully this is at least in the general direction of what you're looking for...

Comment: Many thanks! I have found the answer myself before seeing yours. +1 for the effort, I'll be sure to list down my answer. Thank you again, Jack!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [XPath Filter predicates](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727) in order to return only children of the `<div class="container">` which are greater than the given number.

The relevant expression would be:

```
//div[@class='container']/child::*[number(@class)>24]
```

translated into [Python and Selenium bindings](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io)

```
divNumber = 24

interestingDivs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    "//div[@class='container']/child::*[number(@class)>" + str(divNumber) + "]")

for interestingDiv in interestingDivs:
    print(interestingDiv.get_attribute("class"))
```

See [XPath Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) article for more information